# python itertools dont load files into memory

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have some what big files and I'm trying to get all combinations with this code

```
for text1, text2 in itertools.product(open('text1.txt'), open('text2.txt')):
    t3 = (text1.strip() + text2.strip())
    time.sleep(1)
    print(t3)
```

testing with small files it worked fine but when using big files nothing happens I'm guessing its loading the file into memory anyway so it doesn't load the whole file into memory

Comment: How big are your big files? (How many lines, and how long each line?)

Comment: @9769953 5GB each line is 3 long and 500million+ lines

Comment: 3 long? Characters or words? Doesn't matter too much, but still like to know. And 5GB is really large; that program may run a very very long time.

Comment: @9769953 Characters

Comment: And how large are the test files that work?

Comment: @9769953 not even a Mb

Comment: If it's only two inputs, you could write the nested loop yourself; perhaps that'll work better.

Comment: @9769953 well, it will run into the same problem after the first outer-loop - you need to cache everything eventually or else you can't iterate over the product

Comment: That being said, due to the "resettable" nature of file-iterators, you might be able to hand-code something relatively efficient `.seek`ing back to the beginning, although, you'd have to traverse the "inner" file all the way each time

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, I forgot: the inner iterator will be exhausted after the first outer iteration. So technically, this might only work if you reopen the inner/second file each outer iteration, or rest the file pointer?

Comment: @9769953 yeah, see my answer, this is possible in this particualr case due to the nature of file iterators, but not generally possible with iterators, so `product` has to cache everything (basically making lists out of them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

> Before `product()` runs, it completely consumes the input iterables,
> keeping pools of values in memory to generate the products.
> Accordingly, it is only useful with finite inputs.

Note, in this particular case, you may be able to do something like:

```
with open("text1.txt") as f1, open("text2.txt") as f2:
    for text1 in f1:
        for text2 in f2:
            # do some stuff
            t3 = (text1.strip() + text2.strip())
        f2.seek(0) # reset inner file cursor
```

This is possible due to the nature of file iterators - you can just seek to the beginning and the iterator is effectively reset (and this is nice and efficient too!). But this won't work with iterables or iterators in general, so `itertools.product` handles the general case by simply reifying two lists out fo the iterator

Comment: was just about to ask if that would be the best way to do it thanks for the help